# How to find out programmatically if a NuGet package is provided by and included in the .NET framework runtime or SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I maintain a tool that programmatically resolves the NuGet dependency tree of a project. I am trying to find out how to optionally filter which dependent NuGet packages are provided by the .NET framework runtime or SDK as opposed to be regular non-framework provided deps.

This "classification" happens alright when I run a "dotnet restore": the obj/project-assets.json lockfile lists the packages from the .NET framework runtime and SDK as "PrivateAssets=All", so there is a way to distinguish if a NuGet package is from .Net proper or not, but I have not found how to reproduce this in C# code programmatically.

The tool in question is at https://github.com/nexB/nuget-inspector

Comment: Here is an example: this project https://github.com/nexB/nuget-inspector/blob/main/tests/data/basic/no-dupes/sample.csproj  is resolved this way https://github.com/nexB/nuget-inspector/blob/main/tests/data/basic/no-dupes/sample.csproj-expected.json#L786 and we have some framework provided NuGets such as runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl